# AJAX whenever I try to submit my text my div area duplicates the current data displayed plus my new data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Hi I have a working script of retrieving a JSON data result for my small chat application but my problem is that it displays a duplicate result of the text that was already posted plus my newly text that was inserted from my DB

here is my whole Javascript code:

```
    function sendChatText() {

                if (sendReq.readyState == 4 || sendReq.readyState == 0) {
                    sendReq.open("POST", 'includes/getChat.php?last=' + lastMessage, true);
                    sendReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                    sendReq.onreadystatechange = AjaxRetrieve();  
                    var param = 'message=' + document.getElementById('txtA').value;
                    param += '&name='+user;
                    param += '&uid='+uid;
                    param += '&rid='+document.getElementById('trg').value;
                    sendReq.send(param);
                    document.getElementById('txtA').value = '';
                }                           
            }

function AjaxRetrieve()
            {   

              var rid = document.getElementById('trg').value,
            data = {chat: uid, rid: rid, name: user};
 $.ajax({
      url: "includes/getChat.php",
      type: "GET",
      data: data,
      dataType: 'json',

   success: function(result){

    $.each(result, function(rowKey, row) {

        $("#clog").append($('<p />').html('<h4>'+ row.username +':</h4>' + row.message_content) );
        });
    }

});


}
```

Comment: The problem could be that you're not handling new messages on the server and when you request the new chat messages you are getting previous ones (that are in the log already).

Comment: so can you suggest what I should do? =(

Comment: to rule out this problem check whether getChat.php keeps the same messages on two load instances

Comment: I have tried to run a `console.log` and it returned my latest text in JSON format is this what you mean?

Comment: I meant that you should open `getChat.php` twice in two different tabs in your browser and check whether the second one you opened contained the same messages as the first tab you opened. If it does include duplicates then this is where your duplicates come.

Answer (score 2):

I think your getChat.php returns all the chat text for that user, also you are appending them to #clog.

I have two suggestions

1. Return only the latest text from server by sending the time stamp from the JS itself like

   ```
   data = {"chat": uid, "rid": rid, "name": user, "last_read_time": window.last_read_time};
   window.last_read_time = new Date().format("d/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"); //store new time
   ```
2. clear #clog before looping your data

   ```
   $("#clog").empty(); //clear the previous msgs
   $.each(result, function(rowKey, row) {
       $("#clog").append($('<p />').html('<h4>'+ row.username +':</h4>' + row.message_content);
   });
   ```